# getting HtmlTextWriter of a control

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmltextwriter

is it possible to get  `HtmlTextWriter` of a control?
if no, then how can i call the `RenderEndTag` of a control in code behind?

i am facing a problem in my application. i extended the listbox user control and override its `RenderEndTag` event.

if i used the new listbox (Mylistbox) normally inside a WebPage, everything works fine. but when i put Mylistbox in a `Webusercontrol` and include the `Webusercontrol` in a WebPage, the `RenderEndTag` of the control is not called for some reason.

so i guessed that i should explicitly call 'RenderEndTag' of the control. to do so i need to pass an `HtmlTextWriter`...

Comment: Could you please post what you are trying to achieve in your application?

Comment: check this may help you : http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2007/11/05/dynamically-render-a-web-user-control.aspx

Answer (score 0):

so you are basically saying that somewhere in your code when you call

```
writer.RenderEndTag();
```

it is not adding the endTag because you think you override the RenderEndTag() method.

Please post code of the override / virtual method as well as where you use it.